# View 6+ months of Twitter follower history?

Tags: twitter

Twitter analytics use to graph your followers history but it seems they no longer do that.

Does anyone know of a way to view Twitter follower growth over a period greater than 6 months and graphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Twitter Counter](http://www.twittercounter.com). They charge a monthly fee. Their least expensive (other than free) plan is $6 per month and lets you go back 12 months.